# Java: Why my Euclid GCD function returns incorrect value

Tags: java, recursion, return

I am new to programming and I am learning Java using Think Java. I am trying to do [exercise 10 of chapter 6](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkapjava/html/thinkjava008.html#toc58). The exercise deals with writing a recursive function for finding the greatest common divisor (GCD) using Euclid Algorithm. I came up with 2 ideas. I am not sure why my second idea returns an incorrect value.

This idea works fine:

```
public class exercise10 {
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) return a;
        else return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println(gcd(36,20));
    }
}
```

This idea returns an incorrect value:

```
public class exercise10 {
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b > 0) {
            int r = a % b;
            gcd(b, r);
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println(gcd(36,20));
    }

}
```

This is not part of any class homework. I am simply using the open-source textbook to learn java on my own.

**Running java version 1.7.0_51 on Win64 machine**

Comment: Add a print statement before the if statement

Comment: Second code is working fine for me. may be you are having some other problem.

Comment: @BoristheSpider had pointed out that I omitted `return` in front of `gcd(b, r);`. Adding `return` solved the problem for me.

Comment: I do not understand @sedeh. The codes you provided are working without any trouble.

Comment: @afzalex Maybe it's version issue. Notice I am running java version 1.7.0_51 on Win64 machine.

Comment: @sedeh Sorry, but it cannot be. It is a simple code and I don't think there might be any version issue. Please recheck your code. try to compile it again.

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed things correctly? For instance, it would recurse infinitely if you had written `gcd(r,b)` rather than `gcd(b,r)`, with or without a return.

Comment: @afzalex Ok, I checked again. If by any chance you are using Eclipse, put a breakpoint on line `public static int gcd(int a, int b) {` and do a `Step Into`. You will see it takes you through what appears to be an infinite loop.

Comment: @pjs Good point. I checked again and I have `gcd(b, r)`

Comment: @sedeh I used eclipse, and did not get an infinite recursion with the code as posted. I got a wrong answer, but not an infinite recursion.

Comment: @pjs Please what prints on the console when you run the code?

Comment: It gives 36.  When the `return` is added, it gives 4.

Comment: @sedeh you are posting an [xyproblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Infinite loop is one which will never end. And the problem you are having is that the answer you are getting is incorrect in second code.

Comment: This is your clue that there is a problem. The GCD of 36 and 20 is definitely not 36.

Comment: You are needed to edit your question @sedeh.

Comment: @sedeh Getting an answer of 36 is not demonstrating an infinite anything. Again, I get the *wrong* answer of 36 without a return, the *correct* answer of 4 with a return. In neither case do I get the infinite recursion you described. I can produce an infinite recursion by exchanging the args, but you already stated you didn't do that.

Comment: Sorry if I am incorrecting defining the problem. I will investigate a little further and do any needed revision. When I initially ran the code with some debudding `print` statements, I get 4 and 0 printed on the console "infinitely" and I am forced to terminate the program

Comment: @sedeh Please make sure the code you post is the actual code that produces the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @pjs This is very confusing. When I run it now, I get 36 but that was not the case initially. I worked on the code for good 1 hr and I kept producing what seemed to be a never-ending print of 0 and 4 (i added print statements to print a and b). Now I just get 36 and the code terminates. I wish I can understand what happened, and I am fairly positive I did not edit the code. Anyway, I will edit the question accordingly. Sorry for the run-around.

Comment: As revised, BorisTheSpider's answer was the correct one. Hopefully s/he will repost and you can give her/him credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BorisTheSpider had pointed out what was wrong with my code but his post somehow got deleted. Anyway, he pointed out that my second idea was missing a `return` statement in front of the recursive function `gcd(b, r)`.

```
public class exercise10 {
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b > 0) {
            int r = a % b;
            gcd(b, r); <--- missing return
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println(gcd(36,20));
    }

}
```

So the correct code should be:

```
public class exercise10 {
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b > 0) {
            int r = a % b;
            return gcd(b, r);
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println(gcd(36,20));
    }

}
```

**Credits to BorisTheSpider.**